# How to set timer each 25ms?

Tags: angular, angular8

How to set timer each 25 milliseconds?

```
timer(0.25).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

It is correct?

Comment: its should be as  `timer(25).subscribe(x => console.log(x))`;

Comment: Why 25? if multiply 25 * 1000 it gives 25000 it meant 25 seconds is not?

Comment: @OPV, to convert milliseconds to seconds , you should divide - 25 /1000

Comment: 1000ms  equals to 1 sec and timer take ms as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `timer` API accepts a value of `dueTime` in *milliseconds*, not *seconds*:

> ```js
> timer(dueTime: number | Date = 0, periodOrScheduler?: number | SchedulerLike, scheduler?: SchedulerLike): Observable<number>
> ```
>
> `dueTime`:
>
> Optional. Default is 0.
>
> The initial delay time specified as a Date object or as an integer denoting > *milliseconds* to wait before emitting the first value of 0.
>
> -> From the [docs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/timer) *(emphasis is mine)*

So in this case, as what @SandeepPatel has mentioned, you should pass in a value of `25` (as in 25 milliseconds) instead of `0.25` (as in 0.25 milliseconds):

```js
timer(25).subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```